# How do I give a table a border radius and remove double borders in th and td elements?

Tags: css

I found out that you can't style thead, tr, or tbody. What I want to do is have a 2px white border between the cells and doesn't over lap and give the table a border radius where the table cells don't break the radius.

```css
body {
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px !important;
}
th {
    padding : 12px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
td { 
    padding : 12px; 
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
 <table id="user-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kyle</td>
      <td>bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Brit</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Trevor</td>
      <td>bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Justin</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Dave</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way of going about this?

*Also I tried to add the reset I was using to the code and everything broke because I don't know how to add it before the css that runs in the code snippet example:
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its isn't quite true that you cant style th, tr, td elements in a table. You can see below how the background colour of th & tr is changed.

You can target cells in the corners through pseudo classes such as :first-child, :last-child and add individual border radius property.

In your sample code I've used these properties to mention the borders.

- border-top-left-radius
- border-top-right-radius
- border-bottom-left-radius
- border-bottom-right-radius

```css
body {
 background-color: blue;
 color: white;
}

table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px !important;
}
th {
    padding : 12px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background: red;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
td { 
    padding : 12px; 
    border: 2px solid white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: grey;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="user-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>password</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kyle</td>
      <td>bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Brit</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Trevor</td>
      <td>bb5dc8842ca31d4603d6aa11448d1654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Justin</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Dave</td>
      <td>953f893eaed2098219f31f68947be559</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```